# Validation with controller method accepting just a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Say I have a controller method, that accepts just a string:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string emailAddress)
{
    //
}
```

How could I validate that `emailAddress` isn't null...?
Obviously I can't use DataAnnotations, as I don't have a model?

Comment: the naive question is why not just use a model. You might have one parameter now, but adding another in the future would be easier and less likely to break the method signature. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: In an agile way of working, the additional complexity of creating a model would be done as and when needed. With one property, it's not needed

Comment: I would say the added noise in the controller action (from the solutions) would warrant that tiny additional complexity, but that's just my personal preference. Rules are made to be broken when the solution makes more sense than the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string emailAddress)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailAddress))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("emailAddress", "Please enter an email");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string emailAddress)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress))
        ModelState.AddModelError("emailAddress", "Email address is empty");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return View();
}
```

To show the error, include a ValidationSummary in your view.

Comment: [ValidateInput(False)]   
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string emailAddress) .. this may help